# Is there any OOB approach for expired news?

Tags: sharepoint-online, expiration, sp-online, sharepoint-news

I suppose this question is something we faced off several times in our life. I've never had a clear or good question at all to answer how to accomplish to set as expired news (or any other content) after several days/weeks/months. Is there any OOB mechanism that SharePoint provides? What are the options available to configure something like this?

Moving on this question, now that Microsoft Flow has appeared and has several years in the market, is this a good tool to use in order to set content as expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways available. You can add a page property called expiry date and add a filter to your news web part to hide those expired news.
You can check detailed steps here:https://regarding365.com/expiring-news-across-modern-sharepoint-b4dd8bbb52d1

And you can use flow to update the promoted status to change a news page to a common page. You can modify a built-in page-approval flow and add the action to update the promoted status through api. Or simply add a expiration date for the filter.

Reference:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/issue-when-updating-new-page-promoted-state-in-microsoft-flow/td-p/252582
https://spblog.net/post/2019/03/19/microsoft-flow-beginners-guides-how-to-detect-that-a-page-is-a-sharepoint-news-page

Comment: Do you think using "information management policy" feature mixed with Flow could be a good solution?

Comment: @jaloplo that is an option as you can simply add retention stage and make it expire with information management policy. I think you will not need to use Flow to do anything.